# .net-core Angular: HTTP Post Error 400 with Angular HTTPClient

Tags: c#, angularjs, .net-core

I want to pass a newly created object to my C# controller. But I always get a server error 400 on the HTTP Post Request I make via Angular.

I make a HTTP GET request in the same way but it works without problems.
My C# Controller:

```cs
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SiteSettingsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<SiteSettings> Get()
        {
            return GetAllSiteSettings();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]SiteSettings siteSettings)
        {
            try
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

     }
```

And my Angular Reuqest:

```js
save() {
    const settings: SiteSettings = {
      id: '',
      name: 'Test',
      domain: 'test.local',
      active: false
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify(settings);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'sitesettings', body, httpOptions).subscribe({
      error: error => console.error('There was an error!', error)
    });
  }
```

Comment: 400 status code is Bad Request. Can you post please the content of the response?

Comment: oh my God, so stupid.
I completely missed that.

"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Guid. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 8."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was completely stupid and missed the actual error message.
So stay focused and look closely...

```
0: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Guid. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 8."
```